# PHImageManager.requestImageForAsset returns low-res image in iOS swift

Tags: ios

I'm using Photos framework to handle images in iOS swift.
When I try to get the image by using PHImageManager.defaultImanager().requestImageForAsset(), it works fine for most of images. That function returns two values: one is of scale 1, another is of scale 2. The image of scale 1 is high-res image, and the image of scale 2 is low-res image.
But regarding some of images, it returns only low-res one.

Does anyone know how to get high-res image for every PHAsset ?

Here are my codes:

Regarding some of images, it doesn't return the image of scale 1 (high-res), so it doesn't go through subFuncForDisplayCurrentImage()

```
    var targetSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height)
    var itemOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    itemOptions.networkAccessAllowed = true

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, options: itemOptions) { (result:UIImage!, info:[NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
        if result != nil && result.scale == 1 {
            self.subFuncForDisplayCurrentImage(result, ID: (asset?.localIdentifier)!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to specify `PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat` as the deliver mode.

In the document: [PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageRequestOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode), it states:

> Photos provides only the highest-quality image available, regardless
>   of how much time it takes to load.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That special image is the burst photo. Is there any way to get high-res image from burst photo?

Comment: It has nothing to do with burst photos, which are the same as other photos, the reason that you are getting images with scale == 2 and scale == 1 is because you didn't set any properties of `PHImageRequestOptions`, you should set its `synchronous` to `YES` and `resizeMode` to `PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact`. The default value for `synchronous` is `NO`, which will give you a small size image when a small one is available, and ResizeModeExact guarantees the delivered image is exactly targetSize.

Comment: Awesome! Through your explanation, I fixed my problem. Thank you,Gabbler!

Comment: Some time has passed, but I am getting the same problem when the collection cell is reloaded (even with synchronous/resizeMode options). Any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

To get high quality images add below code

itemOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 13, the method returns first a low-res version of the image. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616964-requestimageforasset?language=objc)

> For an asynchronous request, Photos may call your result handler block more than once. Photos first calls the block to provide a low-quality image suitable for displaying temporarily while it prepares a high-quality image. (If low-quality image data is immediately available, the first call may occur before the method returns.) When the high-quality image is ready, Photos calls your result handler again to provide it. If the image manager has already cached the requested image at full quality, Photos calls your result handler only once. The PHImageResultIsDegradedKey key in the result handler’s info parameter indicates when Photos is providing a temporary low-quality image.

Comment: any method to avoid this first low-quality image, actually I want to get image from array PHAsset in for loop,